# system hangs when factorizing a float instead of an integer

Tags: erlang

I am struggling to understand the cause of this issue. To the point:

1) Passing an integer ( 10 ) to the following factorization function works immediately:

```
test() ->
    X  = 10,
    F  = factorize(X).

factorize(0) -> 1;
factorize(N) -> N * factorize(N-1).
```

2) Passing a float ( **10.0** ) will cause the beam process to hang, taking high CPU and not even terminating. **Notice this is a small value**. I can factorize a high integer number and get an almost immediate response, but a small float number 10.0 will cause it hang.

```
test() ->
    X  = 10.0,          <-- NOTICE THE DOT ZERO 10.0
    F  = factorize(X).

factorize(0) -> 1;
factorize(N) -> N * factorize(N-1).
```

**Question:** why on Erl Earth would this hanging occur with some mere multiplication recurrency of floats ?

Comment: Floating point number operations are not exact. Chances are you never hit the base case with strict equality to zero. (So your CPU is zooming out in the negatives as fast as it can.)

Comment: you nailed it. thanks. pls feel free to add an answer. I added a case condition such as case (N >= 1) and returned 1 in case of false, so probably the matching on factorize(0) did not work for factorize(0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documentation says](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77027), there are two operations to compare equality of terms in Erlang and they differ only in handling integer and floats:

- `=:=` - exactly equal - which counts numbers equal if the types are the same, and their values are the same too `false = (0.0 =:= 0)`
- `==` - equal - counts numbers equal if their values are the same but their types may not be equal `true = (0.0 == 0)`

Pattern matching uses the first one - exactly equal - operator, that's why your function hanged in the second clause.

Another problem with floats is thier approximate value. You can never be sure you have some exact value especially after arithmetic operation. There is a common practice to use small value `epsilon` in floats equality tests.

```
is_zero(F) -> (F < 1.0e-10) andalso (F > -1.0e-10).
```